# Querying XML Rows For New Non-XML Rows

Tags: sql-server, xml

Note: [See this spelled out example on SQL Fiddle, or look at the code below:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7098f/4), as the `DECLARE @XML variable` examples are confusing the syntax when trying to actually obtain XML data from an XML column and intended for non-XML rows:

```
CREATE TABLE ##xml (
    ID TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value XML
)

INSERT INTO ##xml  (Value)
VALUES ('<Animals key="zoo" fish="22" dogs="0" birds="4" />')
    , ('<Animals key="house" fish="0" dogs="1" birds="2" />')
    , ('<Animals key="business" fish="0" dogs="0" birds="12" />')

SELECT *
FROM ##xml

SELECT nodes.child.value('key[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM ##xml.Value.nodes('Animal') AS nodes(child)
-- Errors here, though the syntax looks correct

DROP TABLE ##xml
```

I'm getting the error, "Invalid column name '##xml'.  The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml" even though I'm trying to query the nodes of XML to produce a result like the below:

```
Key      | Fish | Dogs | Birds
Zoo         22     0       4
House        0     1       2
Business     0     0      12
```

Note, if I change the syntax of the FROM statement to point to the specific column (Value), I receive other errors about Value not being a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT  nodes.child.value('@key','varchar(100)')
FROM    ##XML a
        CROSS APPLY a.value.nodes('/Animals') AS nodes(child)
```